# How to use mexsh to link non-.o object files into a mex executable?

Tags: matlab, gcc, makefile, g++, mex

I'm using MATLAB 2015b on Ubuntu 14.04, with GCC 4.8.4.

I'm trying to manage C and C++ code in one Makefile.

The C and C++ code need to use different compiler flags. To solve this problem I'm trying to compile .cpp files to .xo object files and .c files to .o object files, so that I can use different recipe for .xo and .o respectively.

Here's a sample of my Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
MEX=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/mexsh

CFLAGS=-Wall -fPIC -std=gnu99
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -fPIC -std=gnu++11

INCLUDES=/usr/include/boost

LFLAGS=-lm -L/usr/lib -lboost_system -lboost_regex
all: hello asio

hello: hello.o               # hello world example, C code, works fine
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)
asio:asio.xo                 # boost asio example, C++ code, works file
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)
mexAsio:asio.xo
    $(MEX) $^ $(LFLAGS) ############  here, with .xo files as input
                        ############  mex gives "no input file" error
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.xo

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDES)
%.xo: %.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDES)
```

GCC and G++ has no problem linking object files with arbitrary extension, but when I try to use mex to link object files to create a mex executable, mex command only accept .o files.

**Question:**

1) Is there a way to make `mex` accept object files with arbitrary extesnion?

2) Is there another way to compile C++ and C code with different compiler flags rather than using custom extension for object file targets?

Comment: I think you'll get this answered quickly with the makefile tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is there a way to make mex accept object files with arbitrary extension?

No, mex is a wrapper script for other compilers and doesn't accept arbitrary extensions for object files.

> 2) Is there another way to compile C++ and C code with different compiler flags rather than using custom extension for object file targets?

You are already doing this

```
%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDES)
%.xo: %.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDES)
```

I would just change the following in your Makefile:

- `%.xo: %.cpp` -> `%.o: %.cpp`
- `asio:asio.xo` -> `asio:asio.o`
- `mexAsio:asio.xo` -> `mexAsio:asio.o`

You may need to change `$(MEX) $^ $(LFLAGS)` to `$(MEX) -cxx $^ $(LFLAGS)`